# Correct yummly API call for a recipe

Tags: web-services, api, url

I'm trying to use the Yummly API. I've noticed that some of their developers have answered other questions here, so I'm hoping to catch their eye. I used the documentation at the yummly developer site https://developer.yummly.com/documentation#IDs.
Specifically here is my get request:

```
<http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipe/Avocado-cream-pasta-sauce-recipe-306039>
```

Which returns this:
`Please include X-Yummly-App-ID and X-Yummly-App-Key`

Seems like this is a sensible thing, except that I don't see anywhere in the documentation for the single recipe call where I'm supposed to insert that info.  Any one out there know how to properly format this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

or include them as URL parameters:

```
_app_id=app-id&_app_key=app-key
```

https://developer.yummly.com/documentation#IDs

Try this:

http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipe/Avocado-cream-pasta-sauce-recipe-306039?_app_id=ID&_app_key=KEY

Comment: Can you show me the appropriate way? I have already tried this without success.  http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipe/_app_id=<number>&_app_key=<number>&id=Avocado-cream-pasta-sauce-recipe-306039  I'm not a web developer by training so I think there is something here I don't know that other people must take for granted.

Comment: Nope, not yet. :( http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipe/Avocado-cream-pasta-sauce-recipe-306039&_appid=ID&_app_key=KEY although I can see the calls are not being successfully counted against my limit either.

Comment: So... I actually got carried away by the excitement of seeing something other than the error message. This gives me a list of recipes that are matched by the search, which seems to be an alternate call to the API. I think I'll just take this as sufficient for a class project.

Comment: Made a slight edit to your answer because I figured the dang thing out. It was extremely close to what you gave me. Thank you Sparky.

Answer (score 2):

You need to take the URL you mentioned in the question and add your authentication parameters to it. So it becomes:

http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipe/Avocado-cream-pasta-sauce-recipe-306039?_app_id=ID&_app_key=KEY

Instead of ID and KEY insert the application id and key from your account on developer.yummly.com

Comment: This is true. ID and KEY are the place holders I was using to replace those values so that I don't put my keys out on the internets.